# Xamarin: load page as an object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Update: I edited the program, now the problem is that it is not recognizing the children section and the class in the button class

```
public App()
    {
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new buttonPage());
        NavigationPage.PushAsync(new buttonPage.hello());
    }
```

and the buttonPage on the same file

```
  public class buttonPage : ContentPage
{
    public void hello()
    {
        Button hi = new Button
        {
            Text = "GO",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };
        Content = new ContentPage()
        {
            children = { hi }
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/hierarchical/

Answer (score 2):

You need a NavigationPage to wrap your main page so that you can transition to other pages.

If you want your `MenuPage` to have a Back button then you'd use PushAsync, if you want it to replace the current page - PushModalAsync

Also: split your pages in separate classes and files, it quickly becomes way too messy to maintain page-within-page stuff

```
public class App: Application{
  public App(){
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ButtonPage());
  }
...
}

public class ButtonPage : ContentPage{
...
  async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args){
     await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MenuPage());
  }
}
```

Comment: @AleksandrPodyachev you need to share a more complete sample, without the unrelated elements

Comment: I changed it to this

Comment: using Xamarin.Forms;
using ButtonDemoPage;
using System;

namespace Test_app
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new buttonPage());
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
        }
    public class buttonPage : ContentPage
    {
        Button button = new Button
        {
            Text = "GO",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };
    }
}
However, it does not recognize the await method

Comment: Look around StackOverflow and get a good sense on how to post code. It's not in comments, rather update your question and comment here to prompt a response to your updated question.

Comment: @AleksandrPodyachev look carefully at the code you wrote and the sample I gave: you're calling PushAsync from App(), that's not what I suggested - you call that method from the ButtonPage

Comment: @AleksandrPodyachev and just declaring a Button property on your `buttonPage` (capitalize properly) wouldn't show the button - in the constructor you have to add it the way it's added in your code sample